# The recommended way to save an Ember record with relationship to remote server?

Tags: ember.js

I tried to save a `Quote` record with a belongsTo relationship.

My `Quote` model is like this

```
{
  content: DS.attr('string'),
  member:  DS.belongsTo('member')
}
```

My `Quote` record is using this hash for creation

```
{
  "content": params.content, 
  "member": this.store.findRecord('member', params.id)
}
```

I have a form so I pass the data to the route, create a new record and save it.

I understand that Ember Data trying to work out the relationship itself by sending a request to the server because I only gave an id and there is no cached data in the store.

But I am not sure this is normal. Why make another request when an ID of that relationship is all for the server to care about.

So I am wondering..what is the best or recommended practice for Ember?

- Should Ember pre-load all the records that are needed beforehand?
- Should the model contain a `member_id` field?
- or this is really just what must happen - a get request then a post.
- Or not rely on Ember Data convention but manually write some Ajax post code

Comment: The server call only happens, if the member is not in the store yet. You could either overwrite your serializer to accept a models (in your case member) id instead of the record or pass the model to your route. How you transition to your route?

Comment: My concern is the first point. I am not sure if should let the server call to happen. To prevent it, I need to get members into the store firstly. I got your point about serializer which can change the data posted to the server in different format. You mean transition to the current route that I am doing the post? I am not transitioning to. It's just a route on the page.

Comment: Try to avoid using 'content' as a field name when using Ember Data. It's a reserved word in the latest versions, and will likely cause you all sorts of confusing failures (as I experienced). I suggest 'quotedText' or 'quotedContent', or something similar.